# Concatenate JSON to a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Understood that it is a very basic question but I ain't sure why the below code returns object Object even after having done JSON.stringify and both are of type string. Could you please help me understand why and suggest possible ways to concatenate such that whole json is visible

```js
var text = ['here is this', {
  a: 'b',
  c: 'd'
}]

var content = text[0];
var res = (text[1] instanceof Object) ? JSON.stringify(text[1]) : text[1]; //{"a":"b","c":"d"}
var result = text.reduce((content, res) => content += " " + res);
console.log(result) //here is this [object Object]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mis-interpreting `reduce`'s work. It doesn't refer to the variables `content` and `res` which are declared prior to it. Instead, it loops over the `text` array, and concatenate the object to the string.

Note that the variables `content` and `res` in the callback are local to the callback, and are given preference over the ones which were define before `reduce` executes.

You can try the following approaches to correct the code. If you simply require the concatenation, do this:

```
var result = content + ' ' + res;
```

Or if you want to use reduce for this, do it like this:

```js
var text = ['here is this', {
  a: 'b',
  c: 'd'
}]

var result = text.reduce((content, res) => content += " " + (typeof res === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(res) : res));
console.log(result)
```

The snippet above, in each iteration, checks if the current item is an object. If so, it stringifies it first and then concatenates. If not, it concatenates it as it is.

Comment: I guess whatever she wrote is correct and the second option you provided will be more appropriate for more values in the array instead of hard coding with first solution.

Comment: @Sivaprasath -- Yes, that's a mystery because OP hasn't specified what should be the desired approach. That's why, had to provide both the options.

Comment: @31piy Hey, you're right that i misinterpreted reduce itself. the second suggestion of yours was what i was trying to. Am sorry for this blunder. And thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this:

```
var result = content + ' ' + JSON.stringify(text[1]);
```

Read this to understand the `reduce` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: the above code does the same only., i believe. I understand that reduce is unwanted but still...the same would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't need to use reduce, Simply:

```
var text = ['here is this', {
  a: 'b',
  c: 'd'
}]
console.log(text[0] + " " + JSON.stringify(text[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the stringified value to `res` which is a new variable and you are applying reduce to `text` which has a string value and a object value. You need to change this object to stringified object by overwriting `text[1]` with the value of `res` to make it work as expected by you:

```js
var text = ['here is this', {
  a: 'b',
  c: 'd'
}]

var content = text[0];
text[1] = (text[1] instanceof Object) ? JSON.stringify(text[1]) : text[1]; //{"a":"b","c":"d"}
var result = text.reduce((content, res) => content += " " + res);
console.log(result);
```

The `res` parameter in `reduce` is not the same as `var res` because the `res` in `reduce` represent each element of array `text` so you cannot assume that the `res` you have outside the `reduce` with stringified object is same as the `res` parameter in `reduce`.